# Need regex for password requirements

Tags: c#, regex, passwords

I need a regex to test a users password for the following:

Must be minimum 8 characters with alphanumeric format, no more than 4 consecutive numbers, no id in the password (i.e. cannot use: `1234`, `9876`, `abcd`, or `1234abvc`)

I am using `^([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$*%]{8,15})$` currently and it works great, but doesn't account for the consecutive characters piece.  I'm not sure how to add that to the mix.

Any help would be great!

Comment: No more than 4 consecutive numbers? What, may I ask, is the reasoning behind this?

Comment: Do you want to forbid common patterns like “12345”, “qwerty”, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to solve it with regex, just add an negative lookahead assertion. You can test it [here](http://regexr.com?2tdev)

```
^(?!.*\d{4,}.*)([a-zA-Z0-9!@#$*%]{8,})$
```

The added part `(?!.*\d{4,}.*)` does not consume your string, it just checks if there are 4 or more numbers in a row and if so, its false.

Why do you want to limit the passwords to 15 characters? I removed this in my example.

Comment: Oops, I see you had the same idea. +1

Comment: ^(?!.*?[0-9]{4})[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$*%]{8,15}$ is what ended up working.  The requirements are from a client, not me.

Answer (score 5):

It would be far easier to use multiple regular expressions that implement a specific rule than to meld them all into one string.

With that in mind, the consecutives would fail with this sort of regex:

```
"[a-zA-Z]{4}"
  or
"\d{4}"
```

Comment: Also, doing them separately like this will allow you to give different error messages depending which "rule(s)" it failed. E.g., "Pass cannot contain four consecutive digits" instead of issuing a universal "Password invalid" and forcing the user to figure out why.

Answer (score 4):

I can't speak for everyone, but I would prefer to see this instead of a regex:

```
bool IsAcceptedPassword(string password, string id)
{
    if (password.Contains(id)) {
        return false;
    }

    if (password.Length < 8) {
        return false;
    }

    // Adjust allowed characters here
    const string allowedChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789@#$*%";
    const string restrictRunsOf = "0123456789";
    const int MaxRunLength = 4;

    int currentRunLength = 0;
    foreach(var ch in password) {
        if (allowedChars.IndexOf(ch) == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        if (restrictRunsOf.IndexOf(ch) == -1) {
            currentRunLength = 0;
        }
        else if(++currentRunLength > MaxRunLength) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you want to let the caller know *why* the password is not accepted, you can return an `enum` type or throw exceptions. I 'd prefer the `enum` approach.

Answer (score 3):

Easily done with a (*commented*) regex:

```cs
if (Regex.IsMatch(subjectString, 
    @"# Password: 8-15 alphanums but no more than 3 consecutive digits.
    \A                       # Anchor to start of string.
    (?!.*?[0-9]{4})          # No more than three consecutive digits.
    [a-zA-Z0-9!@#$*%]{8,15}  # Match from 8 to 15 alphanum chars.
    \Z                       # Anchor to end of string.
    ", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```